# JSF Problem with using maxInactiveInterval

Tags: jsf, el

Folks, I'm finding that with a test value of 1 minute expiry in web.xml the following code redirects to the given url immediately when the page is rendered:

```
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="${pageContext.session.maxInactiveInterval};url=#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/index.xhtml"/>
```

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `${pageContext}` is only available when you're using JSF on JSP. It seems that you're using JSF on JSP's successor Facelets as you're trying to redirect to a XHTML file. Facelets has totally no notion of a `${pageContext}`. You should be using `#{facesContext}` instead. The session is then available by  `#{facesContext.externalContext.session}`. However, Facelets offers a shorthand to get it: `#{session}`. The same for the `#{request}`.

So, this should do:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="#{session.maxInactiveInterval};url=#{request.contextPath}/index.xhtml"/>
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant BalusC.  Thanks so much.  I get to keep the rest of my hair :-)