# JSF and j_security_check connection

Tags: java, jsf, security

I have an .xhtml page in which I have tried both BalusC's suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141244/j-security-check-connection-interrupted/2141274#2141274) and also the following without avoiding the [OP's issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2141244/54680)

```
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="#{session.maxInactiveInterval}"/>
```

Basically, I start the application and the form based authentication page is rendered.  I then wait for the session time to expire.  If I try to login after that then the [OP's problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2141244/54680) occurs.

Comment: Can you confirm that the page is actually been refreshed by the meta refresh tag? Can you confirm that the `content` attribute contains a sensible value and is indeed the session timeout in seconds? Rightclick page in browser and choose *View Source*.

Comment: Sorry about the messy way of posing the question - will do better next time.  Having checked my login.jsp I found that I was wrong in what I placed where! I now have   <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="${pageContext.session.maxInactiveInterval}"/> I am, again, grateful for such swift response.
in the login.jsp and the following in the index.xhtml   <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="#{session.maxInactiveInterval}"/>
I can confirm that this now ensures the login.jsp is refreshed and when the session expires on index.xhtml then the login.jsp is rendered.

Comment: I reposted it as an answer. I however wonder if you understand the distinction between JSP and Facelets... You've asked a very similar question before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7098831/jsf-problem-with-using-maxinactiveinterval I'd expect that it was clear enough that `${pageContext.session}` can be used in JSP only and `#{session}` in Facelets only, and that Facelets is the successor of JSP (and thus JSP should not be used at all as it's an ancient view technology now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```xml
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="#{session.maxInactiveInterval}"/>
```

The `#{session}` is available in Facelets only. That it doesn't work suggests that you are not using Facelets for this particular view, but its legacy predecesor JSP or even plain vanilla HTML.

For JSP you should be using `${pageContext.session}` to get the session, exactly as demonstrated in my answer on the question which you found yourself.

```xml
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="${pageContext.session.maxInactiveInterval}"/>
```

Or, much better, get rid of legacy JSP altogether and replace it by its successor Facelets.

Comment: Ok thanks BalusC.  I am new to JSF and come from a JSP background. I now get it and will not waste anyone's time in future.  I will see if replacing the login.jsp and loginerror.jsp pages with .xhtml will work in my particular Use case.

Comment: You're welcome. It should be as simple as renaming `.jsp` to `.xhtml`, replacing `<%@taglib prefix="x" uri="uri">` by `xmlns:x="uri"`, etc. Oh, old fashioned *scriptlets* don't work in Facelets, but that's only a Good Thing :)